# ankhsvn repository url is empty

Tags: ankhsvn

i am new to ankhsvn. i downloaded the ankhsvn and installed it successfully. http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_install.html.

on Add to subversion dialog box there is a field Repository Url. The lists shows empty.

my project is saved on my local machine. how can i setup it?

Answer (score 0):

You enter the URL to your repository here, then the big box (which is a tree view of the repository) fills up so you can select a node where to import your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need an SVN server if you do not have one.

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) is free and easy to use.